# Getting query String using HttpClient 4.1

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am migrating to Httpclient 4.1 from HttpClient 3.0
How can I get the query String from the URL.

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient();

client.getHostConfiguration().setHost( pro.getProperty( "host" ),
                Integer.parseInt( pro.getProperty( "port" ).trim() ),
                    pro.getProperty( "protocol" ) );
//client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);

client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope( pro.getProperty( "host" ),
            Integer.parseInt( pro.getProperty( "port" ).trim() ),
                pro.getProperty( "protocol" ) ),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials( user, userpassword ) );

client.getParams().setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true );
authget = new HttpGet( pro.getProperty( "getparam" ) );
HttpResponse response = client.execute( authget );
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

What should I insert here for getting the query string to match from "&".

```
StringTokenizer qryStrToken = new StringTokenizer(***Insert code for getting query string***,"&");

while (qryStrToken.hasMoreTokens()){
    String temp = qryStrToken.nextToken();
    if(temp.startsWith("SMAGENTNAME")){
        smAgentName = temp.substring(temp.indexOf("=")+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to get the query string *out* of the API? Didn't you just put the parameters in there yourself?

Comment: no i have'nt put the parameter in their .. i will get the parameter attached by some another appliction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the getUri method of HttpGet.

```
String uri = authGet.getURI();
```

Comment: if i will use the above method .... i am still not getting the query string , infact i am getting only the URL i.e. www.example.com that i have post the request to via HttpGet

Answer (score 0):

The URI has your query string which you can get by:

URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(request.getRequestLine().getUri()),HTTP.UTF_8);